# msSQL log data - start and end from multiple timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp

i have a table which holds a number of different rows which comes from generated log files.  Each row has a timestamp (in epoch format) below is a sample of data, currently there is about 1.5 million rows of data!

```
EpochTime               Date                    Dbm Source
1370732265.373915000    2013-06-17 11:36:39.477 -85 1
1370732265.376506000    2013-06-17 11:36:39.487 -76 2
1370732265.398012000    2013-06-17 11:37:39.503 -81 1
1370732265.463492000    2013-06-17 11:37:39.520 -94 3
1370732265.692144000    2013-06-17 11:37:39.533 -77 2
1370732265.845195000    2013-06-17 11:38:39.550 -84 4
1370732265.933283000    2013-06-17 11:38:39.580 -84 4
1370732265.935863000    2013-06-17 11:38:39.597 -84 5
1370732265.939143000    2013-06-17 11:39:39.597 -84 2
1370732265.939858000    2013-06-17 11:39:39.613 -84 4
1370732265.965481000    2013-06-17 11:40:39.627 -82 5
1370732266.049712000    2013-06-17 11:40:39.677 -82 3
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:41:39.690 -84 4
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:41:39.690 -84 6
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:42:39.690 -84 3
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:42:39.690 -84 4
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:42:39.690 -84 6
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:43:39.690 -84 2
1370732266.110457000    2013-06-17 11:44:39.690 -84 1
```

What i need to do is find the start and end time for each source, however there can only be a maximum span of 5 minutes before the source gets counted again. i.e. source 1 would get logged twice, all other sources would still continue to be logged until the source hasnt been seen for 5 minutes, into a table that looks like below.

```
ID  Duration    Store       Start                   End                     MacID  Dbm  
    7   31          1       2013-06-08 07:46:10.000 2013-06-08 08:17:00.000 1      -84
    4   2           1       2013-06-08 18:42:53.000 2013-06-08 18:44:06.000 2      -83
    2   1           1       2013-06-08 14:31:20.000 2013-06-08 14:32:08.000 3      -89
    11  213         1       2013-06-08 12:43:55.000 2013-06-08 16:16:11.000 4      -86
    6   585         1       2013-06-08 14:03:58.000 2013-06-08 23:48:44.000 5      -75
    28  287         1       2013-06-08 07:15:40.000 2013-06-08 12:02:10.000 6      -88
    28  287         1       2013-06-08 07:15:40.000 2013-06-08 12:02:10.000 1      -81
```

preferably im looking for a fully SQL solution because of the amount of data that exists, due to performance of looping through that much data.  i have had a go but everything i have done so far only counts the source once per period ( currently set to a days worth of data)

The database is running on sql server 2012

EDIT: one thing not mentioned was that the highest DBM value for each 'visit' needs to be logged with the processed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SQL Server 2012.  Yeah.

Here is the idea.  Find where each sequence for a source begins.  This is either the first time the source is seen or whenever the source has not been seen for five minutes.  You can handle this with the `lag()`.

Next, do a cumulative sum of the `NewStart` flag.  Everything in a sequence has the same value, so this can be used for grouping.

The final results come from aggregation.  All the fields in your output are not clear, but here is SQL to do the bulk of the work:

```
select count(*) as numIds, max(date) - MIN(date) as duration, 1 as store,
       MIN(date) as start, MAX(date) as end, source as MacId
from (select t.*,
             SUM(NewStart) over (partition by source order by date) as Grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when date - lag(date) over (partition by source order by date) < 5/(60*24.0) then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as NewStart
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp
```

Comment: Worked liked a dream! thanks for this, i didnt know about the lag() function, very handy indeed!